# How can I wrap() all elements in one container rather than each element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML similar to the following:

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Title</legend>

   <p>blahblahblah</p>
   <p>blahblahblah</p>
   <p>blahblahblah</p>
</fieldset>
```

What I want to do is wrap all the P's into a single container like so:

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Title</legend>

   <div class="container">
      <p>blahblahblah</p>
      <p>blahblahblah</p>
      <p>blahblahblah</p>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

Here's my current Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('fieldset legend').click(function()
   {
      $(this).siblings().wrap('<div class="container"></div>');
   });
});
```

That, however, causes each P element to be wrapped in it's own div.container. Like so:

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Title</legend>

   <div class="container"><p>blahblahblah</p></div>
   <div class="container"><p>blahblahblah</p></div>
   <div class="container"><p>blahblahblah</p></div>
</fieldset>
```

Is there a neater way to accomplish this rather than using something like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('fieldset legend').click(function()
   {
      $(this).after('<div class="container"></div>');
      $(this).parent().append('</div>');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the wrapAll() method.

So something like this.

```
$("fieldset").children("p").wrapAll('<div class="container"></div>');
```

Comment: Completely forgot about that function :/ Cheers.

Comment: No problems - please mark as correct if this answered your question :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can also do something like this

```
$('fieldset').find('p').wrapAll('<div class="container" />');
```

Have a Good Day !!